# My array is undefined Angular2

Tags: angular

I want put 10 numbers in my Array , but I get undefined

```
public arrayDrag: number[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.arrayDrag = new Array(); //or   this.arrayDrag = new Array(10)
}

  rowDragEnd(event) {
    let max = 0;
    this.arrayDrag = new Array();  //or   this.arrayDrag = new Array(10)

    this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function(node) {
      if (max < 10) {
        this.arrayDrag.push(node.data.point);
        console.log('add', node.data.point);
        max += 1;
      }
    });
  }
```

I declared to arrayDrag with (0) or (10) and when my event is calls (rowDragEnd), I get error "undefined" the  `this.arrayDrag.push(`

Comment: What's the _full error_?  Are you sure that the issue isn't `node.data.point`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an arrow function to maintain the scope to your component.

```js
this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((node) => {
  if (max < 10) {
    this.arrayDrag.push(node.data.point);
    console.log('add', node.data.point);
    max += 1;
  }
});
```

In the code you posted you are using a `function` so `this` refers to the function and not your component.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, But I don't understand why with function () {} undefined ... can you tell me ?

Comment: When you declare a function as `function () {}` within the function `this` refers to the function and not the component so the function does not have a property of `arrayDrag`. When you declare the function as `() => {}` then within the function `this` refers to the outer scope.